# Ajax posting hitting action without authentication with CanCan And Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery, devise, cancan

I am using Cancan to authorize my comments resource and devise to authenticate. I have the following controller, when I am not signed in using devise and trying to post a new comment, the user will be redirect to the sign in page(new_user_session_path), since they have to sign in to create comment. However, if I post the new comment use `remote: true` without signing in, it is hitting the action, by rendering the `create.js.erb` and responding with a html in Chrome console with an error while parsing `@comments.any?`, which is supposed to be nil. However, I want to get a status code like :unauthorized or 501 instead if the user hasn't signed in but want to submit the comment, so I can catch it with jQuery and bring up the Sign In form. I thought the `gem cancan` provided `load_and_authorize_resource` will prevent my request from even hitting the action, but apparently it is not. What should I do to get the status response and not hitting the action? Thank you!

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  #should I also add a devise authenticate_user! before filter here?

  def create
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment].merge(:commentable => @commentable))
    if @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @commentable, :notice => "Successfully created comment."}
        format.js   {@comments = @commentable.comments}
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @commentable, :notice => "Comment NOT created."}
        format.js   { render :status => :internal_server_error }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would revise your controller to this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationControlle

  def create
    @commentable = find_commentable
    authorize! :create, @commentable
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment].merge(:commentable => @commentable))
    if @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @commentable, :notice => "Successfully created comment."}
        format.js   {@comments = @commentable.comments}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If your user is authorized than your success message will appear.  Otherwise a 501 message will appear when an unauthorized user tries to leave a comment.